# Failed to get driver instance for oracle

Tags: spring, oracle, hibernate, spring-boot

I’m trying to connect to my oracle database, I’m using a spring boot configuration together with YAML file, I’ve configured jdbc in pom and jpa, but it still fails to connect.

I’ve tried many different configuration for the url:

```
1)  jdbcUrl=jdbc:oracle:thin://test.test.test:1521

2)  jdbcUrl=jdbc:oracle:thin@test.test.test:1521 

3)  jdbcUrl=jdbc:oracle://test.test.test:1521 

4)  jdbcUrl=jdbc:oracle@test.test.test:1521
```

here my application.yml

```
spring:
  profiles: test
datasource:
  onlineterminierung:
    url: jdbc:oracle: jdbc:oracle:thin://test.test.test:1521
    database: test
    username: test
    password: test
    driverClassName: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
    defaultSchema:
    maxPoolSize: 20
    hibernate:
      hbm2ddl.method: update
      show_sql: false
      format_sql: true
      dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
```

and here the DataSource bean:

```
  /*
     * Configure HikariCP pooled DataSource.
     */
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DataSourceProperties dataSourceProperties = dataSourceProperties();
        HikariDataSource dataSource = (HikariDataSource) DataSourceBuilder.create(dataSourceProperties.getClassLoader())
                .driverClassName(dataSourceProperties.getDriverClassName()).url(dataSourceProperties.getUrl()).username(dataSourceProperties.getUsername())
                .password(dataSourceProperties.getPassword()).type(HikariDataSource.class).build();
        dataSource.setMaximumPoolSize(maxPoolSize);
        return dataSource;
    }
```

here the pom:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
      <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
      <version>10.2.0.3.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

here the stack:

```
HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : Failed to get driver instance for jdbcUrl=jdbc:oracle:thin://test.test.test:1521
    Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to get driver instance for jdbcUrl=jdbc:oracle:thin://test.test.test:1521
    Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
```

Some idea?

Comment: jdbc:oracle:thin@<HOST>:<PORT>:<DATABASE_NAME>

Comment: jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:port:db","usname","pwd"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Syntax:

> jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:port:db","usname","pwd"

```
@Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;



@Bean(name = "dataSource")
public DriverManagerDataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource driverManagerDataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    driverManagerDataSource.setDriverClassName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
    driverManagerDataSource.setUrl("jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname:1521/dbname");
    driverManagerDataSource.setUsername("uname");
    driverManagerDataSource.setConnectionProperties(getadditionalJpaProperties());
    driverManagerDataSource.setPassword("password");
    return driverManagerDataSource;
}

Properties getadditionalJpaProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    // properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create-drop");
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect");
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");

    return properties;
}
```

Comment: Can you add above to your configuration by modfying host details and others .It worked for me

Comment: thanks man, now i get error: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor; do you know what could it be?

Comment: have you connected to db manualy using toad or sql developer?

Comment: Sure and what I noticed is that i set by a oracle thin connection always the property "service", which im missing in this case. Do you know how could i set it?

Comment: You need to set in the url only driverManagerDataSource.setUrl("jdbc:oracle:thin:@service:1525/

Comment: You mean you don't have service attribute for your connection

Answer (score 2):

Always use the long form of the connection URL that gives you the flexibility to pass various connection level parameters.   A code sample [DataSourceSample](https://github.com/oracle/oracle-db-examples/blob/master/java/jdbc/ConnectionSamples/DataSourceSample.java) on GitHub has a sample URL for reference.

jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(HOST=myhost)(PORT=1521)(PROTOCOL=tcp))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=myorcldbservicename)))";

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem. and I was mistakenly ignoring a line of code

`driverManagerDataSource.setDriverClassName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");`

or in bean config

`<property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />`

I am using Oracle 11G and Jersey + Boot server running on Websphere