# Error when running WAR file on Tomcat server

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I built the WAR file of my application https://github.com/JonkiPro/REST-Web-Services. I put it on the Tomcat server and clicked `START`. Then he threw the error https://zapodaj.net/44f410f8abc74.png.html

```
FAIL - Application at context path [/WebApplication] could not be started
FAIL - Encountered exception [org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: start: ]

java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to get driver instance for jdbcUrl=jdbc:h2:mem:database
```

and wrote in the logs https://pastebin.com/7rWhPFLt.

I will mention that the application after compilation in IntelliJ works without a problem.

My application works on port `8443`. I do not know if it matters. It seems to me that Tomcat has a database problem?

Comment: Hey buddy. Your question is a good one IMHO at its base, however it is difficult and inconvenient to follow due to your posting of errors/logs as off site resources such as images and log dumps. Please embed this data directly in your questions in the future, starting with the current question. This also allow an easy way to quote your additional information. Thanks and good luck!

Comment: agreed. The root of the problem is `java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to get driver instance for jdbcUrl=jdbc:h2:mem:database` - you should include that in the question

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44521565/failed-to-get-driver-instance-for-oracle make sure you are adding the jdbc drive correctly. the application cannot find the driver to make the db connection